# Loopback 4 + MySQL: Character set 'utf32_bin' cannot be used in conjunction with 'binary' in call to regexp_like

Tags: mysql, loopback4

I am using loopback 4 with mysql 8.0.22. When I want to execute the following:

```
let orders = await this.orderRepository.find({
    where: {events: {regexp: new RegExp(`.*"id":${event.id}.*`)}},
  });
```

I am getting the following error:

```
500 Error: UNKNOWN_CODE_PLEASE_REPORT: Character set 'utf32_bin' cannot be used in conjunction with 'binary' in call to regexp_like.
```

On my local host this seems to be working fine and I am not sure why.

How can I fix this?

Comment: The string literal used as a pattern is treated as a literal with charset/collation set in connection properties. Either alter them or use explicit convertion to needed collation.

Comment: please check table character set, events field is string and sql query which is being executed is correct

Comment: can you share schema you created and table structure with column definitions

Comment: What, if anything, is in MySQL's log/err files?

Comment: Please show the generated SQL.

Answer (score 2):

`loopback-connector-mysql` adds `BINARY` to the query if you use a case sensitive RegExp:

https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-connector-mysql/blob/c681b2dbe72b4cf9e75ccc7016f1fc2e8ef6cd1d/lib/mysql.js#L556

MySQL 8.0.22 does not allow `REGEXP BINARY` on "nonbinary" types (CHAR, VARCHAR, TEXT, etc.)

It doesn't matter if it's UTF-8/16/32.

---

A simple solution could be to use a case insensitive RegExp:

```js
let orders = await this.orderRepository.find({
    where: {events: {regexp: new RegExp(`.*"id":${event.id}.*`, "i")}},
});
```

---

Or change the field into a binary type. Like VARBINARY, BLOB, etc. (or JSON if you are storing data in that format).

Answer (score -1):

I recommend utf8, not utf32.

utf8 and utf16 and utf32 are different character sets.

Very few people use utf16 and essentially no one uses utf32.

utf32 uses 4 bytes for every character, hence it is quite inefficient with space.

I think (without proof) that 8.0's Regexp processor only handles utf8.

utf8_bin is one of several "collations" for the utf8 "character set".

Comment: I am getting the same error when I use utf8 or utf16